# multiple tables join in MYSQLs

Tags: mysql

I have two tables below:

**Table 1**

| incident_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 976 | 640 |
| 980 | 640 |
| 976 | 641 |
| 976 | 642 |

**Table 2**

| incident_id | user_id | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 976 | 640 | CR |
| 980 | 640 | CC |
| 976 | 641 | CR |
| 976 | 642 | CR |

When I join Table 1 with Table 2 through Left Join and get the outcome from Table 2, it doesn't fetch the correct Outcome for user_id 640. It fetches same Outcome (CR only) for both the incident_ids.
Please provide correct sql syntax.

[image]

This is the query I'm running:

```
SELECT table1.incident_id, table1.user_id, table2.outcome
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.user_id = table1.user_id
GROUP BY table1.incident_id, table1.user_id
```

Comment: `SELECT table1.incident_id, table1.user_id, table2.outcome  FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 USING (incident_id, user_id);`. GROUP BY not needed.

Comment: You're joining on `user_id` column, and as it's duplicated in both sides it gives a grand total of 4 output rows. This is normal and expectable. Could your join condition be on `user_id` and `incident_id` instead?

Comment: @Alejandro Can you write SQL syntax please?

Comment: @Akina I guess This is the right syntax. It is solved now. Than you so much.